# How to add all items in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I was trying to make a definition that would add all numbers within each sublist in a list of lists.

```
def MassAddition(_list):
    output = []
    total = 0
    for i in _list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            output.append(MassAddition(i))
        else:
            total = total + i
    output.append(total)
    return output
```

Problem is that it returns an extra item in a list at the end. I think its because I made total = 0 and then appended it to output list outside of for loop. Can someone help me clean this up? 
Ps. This definition should be able to handle any level of nested lists.

example:
`input = [[0,1,2], [2,1,5],[2,2,2],2,2,1]`
`desiredoutput = [[3],[8],[6],5]`

Thank you,

Comment: Just do: `desiredOutput = map(sum, input)`

Comment: wow. really? i had no clue sum existed. LOL. thanks!

Comment: Why not take out `output.append(total)` and just `return output, total`?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a sublist at the end? `[..., [2, 2, 1]]`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi no, I am assuming that i might get a mix of lists and actual values. I think i can handle it from here though.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. I ran your function on your example input and it returned the desired output.

Comment: Interesting question about flattening [lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida what about an input that is [[2,2,1],[1,2],[2,2]] which will return an extra output with a [0] in it.

Comment: @konrad - hacky solution, loop through the list and delete any indexes that are 0

Comment: `if total: output.append(total)`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Better would be `if total==0: output.append(total)`

Comment: It sounded like he _didn't_ want an extra `0` if there were no bare `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the additional numbers for type too. If they can only be `int`:

```
def mass_addition(lst):
    output = []
    total = 0
    extra_flag = False
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            output.append(mass_addition(i))
        elif isinstance(i, int):
            extra_flag = True
            total += i
    if extra_flag:
        output.append(total)
    return output
```

Comment: if the list is nested as so: [[1,2], [[1], [2], [3,4]]]. The output still contains nested lists - [[3], [[1], [2], [7]]]. is this what the OP wants?

Comment: @EpsilonX, I'm not sure, but if it isn't, the problem must be defined more clearly. That would mean the problem with the original function wasn't just returning an extra item in the end of the list, as konrad said.

Comment: I think the main problem is that, indeed, we don't know what the OP wants.

Comment: True. @PauloAlmeida Perhaps both are the problem??